# add class to root of branch in HMENU

Tags: menu, typo3

Hello I have structure of my site like this

Site A

-> Site A1

-> Site A2

-> Site A3

Site B
 -> Site B1

Now In my HMENU when I'm on Site A or Site B I have on it class "active" so it has diffrent background. I want to keep that class when I'm in Site A1, A2, A3 (make active Site A) and when I'm on B1 i want to make active Site B

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you really mean "site" or are we talking about regular pages and their subpages?
If it is the latter, you should go for the different menu item states.

NO, CUR, ACT, IFSUB, ACTIFSUB and the like are described here:
http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/MenuObjects/CommonItemStates/Index.html

Comment: could you tell something more ? Cause non of this states is accurate for my situation. CUR isn't good cause I'm not in current page but in subpage